# Counting created objects over 2 different classes leads to problems

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

I want to count created objects. If I do this with one class it is easy, but I want count objects from 2 different classes with 2 different counters interacting with each other.
Simplified example:

```
template <class Obj>
class Counter1
{
    private: 
        static int total1;
    public:
        Counter1(){++total1;}
        .. destuctor, copy constructor ..
       static int getCounter1() {return total1;}
       static void setCounter1(int var) {total1 = var;}
};
template<class Obj> int Counter1<Obj>::total1(0);

template <class Obj>
class Counter2
{
    private: 
        static int total2;
    public:
        Counter2(){++total2;}
        .. destuctor, copy constructor ..
       static int getCounter2() {return total2;}
       static void setCounter2(int var) {total2 = var;}
};
template<class Obj> int Counter2<Obj>::total2(0);

class Test1 : private Counter1<Test1>
{
 .. some code ..
};
Test1::Test1() : Counter1()
{
   int tmp_var;
   tmp_var = Counter2<int>::getCounter2();
}
```

Sadly `tmp_var` never gets a valid number. Or in other words, it stays at zero and doesn't increase. What am I doing wrong?

_________________EDIT__________________ 
Here a more detailed example as requested:

```
template <class Obj>
class Counter1
{
    private:
        static int total1;

    public:
        Counter1() {++total1;}
        Counter1(const Counter1& countObj) {if(this != &countObj) {++total1;}}
        ~Counter1() {--total1;}

        static int getCounter1() {return total1;}
        static void setCounter1(int var){total1 = var;}
};
template <class Obj> int Counter1<Obj>::total1(0);

template <class Obj>
class Counter2
{
    private:
        static int total2;

    public:
        Counter2() {++total2;}
        Counter2(const Counter2& countObj) {if(this != &countObj) {++total2;}}
        ~Counter2() {--total2;}

        static int getCounter2() {return total2;}
        static void setCounter2(int var){total2 = var;}
};
template <class Obj> int Counter2<Obj>::total2(0);

/* Memory are with a static Size with variable object Size allocator */
class Class1 : private Counter2<Class1>
{
    public:
        Class1();

        .. some methods ..

    private:
       .. some members ..
    };

/* Constructor */
Class1::Class1() : Counter2()
{
    const int varTotal1 = Counter1<int>::getCounter1();
    const int varTotal2 = getCounter2()-1;

    .. some code ..
}

.. some methods ..

class Class2 : private Counter1<Class2>
{
    public:
        Class1 _PoolsObj[TASKS_PER_PROCESS];

        Class2();
};

Class2::Class2() : Counter1()
{
    _PoolsObj[TASKS_PER_PROCESS] = {};

    /* Reset the task counter */
    Counter2<int>::setCounter2(0);
}

static Class2 class_pool[64];
```

I have two problems: 

 1) `Counter2<int>::setCounter2(0);` doesn't work

 2) `const int varTotal1 = Counter1<int>::getCounter1();` Is always 0

Comment: What does `tmp_var` receive, and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: each template instantiation gets its own set of `static` members, ie `Counter1<Foo>` and `Counter<Bar>` have independent `total1`. Most likely you dont need both `Counter1` and `Counter2`

Comment: please show real code, preferably a [mcve]

Comment: Do note that since your classes are templates each different template type will have its own static members.  For example a `Counter1<int>` and a `Counter1<double>` have different `total1`'s.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. In the current state, of your example, we can't copy-paste your code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please post some real code. `Counter2(){++total1;}` wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Quentin tmp_var stays at zero and never increments. I updated my inital post with a more complex code sample.

Comment: @tobi303 I updated my inital post, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @NathanOliver I updated my inital post, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @molbdnilo I updated my inital post. You are right, it was a typo (++total2)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I updated my inital post, I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, what I was doing wrong and I made some major improvements. 
1) Thanks to the comment of @tobi303 I could remove one counter and only use one for different objects. 
2) I had a semantical error inside of my code. `_PoolsObj[TASKS_PER_PROCESS] = {};` is completly wrong. I wanted to initalize all array elements with 0, but this only called the constructor a fifth time and set the forth (TASK_PER_PROCESS) element to 0. I now placed the initialize list after the variable declaration to ensure proper creation. 
3)

```
public:
        Class1 _PoolsObj[TASKS_PER_PROCESS];
```

This is of course not the nice way, so I included a getter function and set the array to private. 
4) My problems were cause by this two lines of code:

```
Counter1<int>::getCounter1();
Counter2<int>::setCounter2(0);
```

The type should not be int, it should be the class name:

```
Counter1<Class2>::getCounter();
Counter2<Class1>::setCounter(0);
```

I think I set and get a counter for int and not for my classes.

Here my fixed code just for completion:

```
template <class Obj>
class Counter
{
    private:
        static int total;

    public:
        Counter() {++total;}
        Counter(const Counter& countObj) {if(this != &countObj) {++total;}}
        ~Counter() {--total;}

        static int getCounter() {return total;}
        static void setCounter(int var){total = var;}
};
template <class Obj> int Counter<Obj>::total(0);

class Class1 : private Counter<Class1>
{
    private:
        int member;

    public:
        int getMember();
        Class1();
};

class Class2 : private Counter<Class2>
{
    private:
        Class1 _PoolsObj[TASKS_PER_PROCESS] = {};
    public:
        Class1 getPool(int index);
        Class2();
};

Class1::Class1()
{
    const int varTotal1 = Counter<Class2>::getCounter()-1;
    const int varTotal2 = getCounter()-1;

    std::cout<<"varTotal1: "<<varTotal1<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"varTotal2: "<<varTotal2<<std::endl;
}

int Class1::getMember()
{
    return member;
}


Class2::Class2()
{
    std::cout<<"Class2 Constructor"<<std::endl<<std::endl;

    /* Reset the task counter */
    Counter<Class1>::setCounter(0);
}

Class1 Class2::getPool(int index)
{
    return _PoolsObj[index];
}

static Class2 class_pool[64];
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your new sample, the following is my opinion.
First of all, do not forget that each instance of the template has its own static variable. It is not like other standard classes. That is what is playing a trick on you.

The reason

```
const int varTotal1 = Counter1<int>::getCounter1();
```

is always 0 is the instance of the template counter1 is inherited by class2.  But you are asking the counter1's  getCounter1() from class1 to give you the count or the value of total1.  Class1 does not know about getCounter1(). Note that when instantiating the class using the following line of code in your sample code total1 of counter1 is incremented rightly as you are instantiating Class2 and Class2 knows about getCounter1() and if you happen to include getCounter1() in Class2 you can see the total1 value.

```
static Class2 class_pool[64];
```

As to the following code as far as I can tell it works.

```
Counter2<int>::setCounter2(0);
```

As a final note, if I were you I will have only one template say counter. Use that as you do normally to control count of created objects for each class. If you want to see the count of one class from another class why not create a third utility shared class where you can store the counts of the objects. Or you can use mixin to combine the classes as required (using inheritance and composition), but may be this is an overkill.

By the way, your code is not complete you missed to define

```
 TASKS_PER_PROCESS  in 
  _PoolsObj[TASKS_PER_PROCESS] = {};
   I added the following to just compile your code ..
   #define TASKS_PER_PROCESS 10
```

Comment: not sure if your incomplete code is any better than OPs incomplete code...

Comment: @tobi303 I just have changed the original code just to show him he can increment   the counter 2.  This is not meant to correct his code just to show him it might be brute-forced to do what he wants albeit maybe in a wrong way. But he knows better and maybe he has scenario to implement such code so I am putting the ball in his court so to speak ... hope you understand

Comment: Sorry, no I dont really understand. I am almost certain that the `return total1++; ` is a typo in OPs question but not his original code, because it would not compile hence no wrong numbers for `tmp_var` as OP reports. You fixed that typo, but I am pretty sure that the problem in the original code is still unsolved and it will be unless OP shows real code

Comment: His question is: Sadly tmp_var never gets a valid number. What am I doing wrong?  so the way I understood this is he is unable to get a valid number.  And only based on given info the reason is he is not incrementing or setting counter2. So without dealing with the unknown, I showed him the sample code is not properly coded to get the values. That is all.